# In comments - how do I highlight with back-ticks when the last character is a backslash

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

In **comments** there's strange behaviour with ending code markup in backslashes. This works just fine here, but not in comments:

> `First-highlight\`-xyz`Next-highlight`

Instead it overruns as:

> `First-highlight\-xyz`Another-highlight`

For example:

> [image]

This should come out as: `testing testing\`123`testing` and works just fine here, but in comments it appears as:

> [image]

Likewise, `testing\` works just fine here, but the backslash is ignored in comments and it comes out as just `testing`.

How do I do this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: So...you can't write `First-highlight\`-xyz`Next-highlight` in comments? Ooh, I see...how about `First-highlight\ `-xyz `Next-highlight`? Are the spaces problematic?

Comment: Yes - a markable limitation.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the rules for inline code in posts and comments.

**POSTS**: If you want backticks inside an inline code snippet, surround them with any amount of backticks not used in the code. Examples:

- ``` ``this is a `backtick` thing`` ``` renders as `` this is a `backtick` thing ``
- ````` ````here are one ` two `` three ``` backticks```` ````` renders as ```` here are one ` two `` three ``` backticks ````
- Use spaces if backticks are at beginning or end - ``` `` $` `` ``` renders as `` $` ``
- `` `testing testing\`123`testing` `` renders as `testing testing\`123`testing`

**COMMENTS**: Simply use `\` to escape backticks. Limitation: you can't escape backslashes, so you can't have a backslash at the end of an inline code snippet. Also, `` `test`123`test` `` doesn't work.

- `` `this is a \`backtick\` thing` `` renders as  `` this is a `backtick` thing ``
- etc.
- `` `testing testing\ `123 `testing` `` renders as `testing testing\` 123 `testing`